# Repeating Channel Fields within ExpressionEngine

Tags: expressionengine

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to define a Channel Field Group and then allow a user to create repeatable instances of it within a Channel Entry? I'd like to set up a Channel for Tutorials. Each Tutorial entry consists of a number of steps and each step consists of a block of text with an optional embedded image etc.

thanks,
C.

Answer (score 1):

You want Pixel and Tonic's [Matrix](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix) add-on.